# custom progress bar AngularJS responding accordingly to a list of items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am creating a progress bar. now i was trying to attach list of values with the checkbox with the progress bar , means when the checkbox get checked/unchecked the progress bar responds accordingly . the html is :
progress_bar.hmtl

```html
<html ng-app="Progress">
<head>
 <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src = "progresss.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-controller="progress-controller">
  <div progressbar="list"></div>
  <ul class="todo-list">
      <li ng-repeat="list in lists" ng-model="list">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="" >{{list}}</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

progresss.js :

```js
angular.module("Progress", [])
.controller("progress-controller", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.lists = ["fruits" , "eggs" , "grocery"];
}])
.directive('progressbar', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'progress': '=progressbar'
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.progressbar({
                lists: $scope.progress
            })

            $scope.$watch(function() {
                $element.progressbar({lists: $scope.progress})
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

this i tried so far and stuck .... please help me out how to achieve this. thanks

Comment: Do you want the progress-bar to grow/shrink according to the amount of check-boxes selected?

Comment: yes @walt suppose if i have 4 check box and only 3 are checked then the progress bar will be filled 75% almost .. and from those 3 if one more uncheked then again the progress bar become half fill .. and so on

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a directive and the [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive. Please see working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgzuopb0/1/)

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="ItemsController as vm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 border">
            <div class="form-horizontal" data-checkbox-progress="" data-items="items">
                <div class="checkbox" data-ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"> {{item.label}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
angular.module('application', [])
.directive('checkboxProgress', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            items: '=items'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.items = scope.items || [];
            scope.progressStyle = function () {
                var count = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.items.length; i++) {
                    if (scope.items[i].checked) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                var total = ((count / scope.items.length) * 100).toString() + '%'
                return {
                    'width': total
                }
            };

            var progressbar = angular.element('<div class="progress-wrapper"><div class="progressbar" ng-style="progressStyle()"></div></div>');
            $compile(progressbar)(scope, function (clonedElement) {
                element.prepend(clonedElement);
            });
        }
    };
}]).controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        label: 'Item 1'
    }, {
        label: 'Item 2'
    }, {
        label: 'Item 3'
    }, {
        label: 'Item 4'
    }];
}])
```

**Explanation**:

The directive adds the progress bar before the element the directive is called on.

We have to use the `$compile` service before we add the progressbar element to the DOM as the element contains angular code.

The `scope.progressStyle` is a function that returns a object whose keys are CSS style names and values are corresponding values for those CSS keys.(width:100%)

Comment: @walt thnx man .. but what are those classes , and where it is used like :
col-md-4 border,row,form-horizontal,checkbox ??

Comment: `.col-md-4` `row` `form-horizontal` and `checkbox` are bootstrap classes. http://getbootstrap.com/css/ `border` is my own class to create a border. Please remember to mark as the answer if it helped.